# Ruby on Rails instance variable caching based on parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am storing users miscellaneous data in user_data table and when I am retrieving that data with the association I defined and then I am actually caching it using Ruby instance Variable caching like this.

```
def user_data(user_id)
  @user_data || = User.find(user_id).data 
end
```

but instance variable `@user_data` will be allocated value only first time when it's nil and once it hold data for a user lets say for user_id equal to 1,and when I am passing user_id 2 in this method it's returning data for user_id 1 , because it will not allocate new value to it so my question is how can I cache it's value based on parameters of function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [Caching with Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching). Rails can cache data on multiple levels from full page caching to fragment caching, I strongly advise you to read all this page so you can make a perceived choice.

For the low-level caching you can do this:

```
@user_data = Rails.cache.fetch("user_#{user_id}", expires_in: 1.hour) do
  User.find(user_id).data
end
```

By default Rails stores cache on disk, but you can setup for memcache, memory store, and etc.

Comment: This is how you would implement it using the Rails caching. This is not to be confused with instance variable caching though, which the question is about.

Upvoted :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a hash for a key-based intance-variable-cache. I think that does what you want.

```
def user_data(user_id)
  @user_data ||= {}
  @user_data[user_id.to_i] || = User.find(user_id).data 
end
```

Comment: This approach causes @user_data to grow without bound. Keep your total cache-able dataset size in mind if considering something like this.